# When I changed the grub.cfg file, the Arch Linux boot image gives an error

Tags: archlinux

I changed the file /boot/grub/grub.cfg by commenting out the line
`play 600 988 1 1319 4`
and Arch Linux stopped starting and wrote an error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22ZLl.png)

I tried google the error, but it didn't yield any results.

If so, I tried it on VirtualBox